# PyQt4 Windows: Connecting QMainWindow to QWidget to QWidget

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

So I am creating a GUI for work. I want to create:

1. A MainWindow which has links to the company website, a tutorial, and a pushbutton called "Let's explore" which signals to QWidget to open up to the explorer options (in the #6.29.2016 portion)
2. From the QWidget explorer window which has 4 push buttons I want to create a connected QWidget that will open up depending on which pushbutton is choosen (shown in the #7.1.2016 - for explorer window portion). In the code I generated, I ended up making a separate MainWindow for the explorer poriton and creating a connecting QWidget.

I am unsure as to what the best means of making connection is. Online documentation made it seem that you can't connect a QWidget to a QWidget and I would appreciate any suggestions that you may have in regards to creating the connection between the windows as well as other suggestions for the code.

The code was inputted into an iPython notebook from Anaconda using Python 2.7.

https://github.com/OrysyaStus/Creating_GUIs_using_PyQt4/blob/master/Copy%20PCCLE.ipynb

Comment: Can you quote the documentation that _made it seem that you can't connect a QWidget to a QWidget_? Also, does your program work or not? If not, please include the error. If you are looking for general suggestions for improving your code, this is the wrong site. Better post at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: The code works but currently I have 2 pieces of code that I would like to combine, into 1 piece but do not know how to make the connection. Generally, how would you create a pushbutton in a QWidget which opens up to a separate QWidget while closing the first QWidget?

Comment: I ended up using a different formatting for the GUI. But in general, is it possible to create a pushbutton in one QWidget window which opens up to a separate QWidget window while closing the first QWidget window? It might be helpful in the future for me.

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Just create a new window and call `new_window.show()` on it. After that, close the current window with `self.close()` (assuming here that you are in a method of the old window, so that `self` refers to the old window).

Comment: Great thanks! I will see if I will need this in the future.